# Progress bar to fill percentage when textfields are entered in Swift 4

Tags: swift, view, boolean, progress

I am making an app for learning purposes that has static cells and I have a progress bar at the top of the view that I want to start at zero. When they fill in all fields it completes the progress bar and then a button appears saying save. I thought this way would work.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


    @IBOutlet var infoProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    //all labels for adjusting same space
    @IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!

    //textfields for progress
    @IBOutlet var infoTextFields: [UITextField]! {
        didSet{
            infoProgressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
        }
    }


    //progress bar code
    var progress:Float {
        if textFieldProgress(count: true) {
            return Float(infoTextFields) / Float(infoTextFields)
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    //function to check if there is info in textfields
    func textFieldProgress(count: Bool) -> Bool {
        if infoTextFields?.isEmpty ?? true {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

I have all textfields linked to infoTextFields. if I the bool functions return to false the progress bar immediately completes. if I set it to false it goes from half to zero and never comes back.

Here's my view

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce to check how many fields are empty and divide by the total number of text fields:

```
var progress: Float {
    return Float(infoTextFields.reduce(0) { $1.text?.isEmpty == true ? $0 : $0+1}) / Float(infoTextFields.count)
}
```

You will need to add a target to your text fields for editing changed control event because didSet doesn't get called when you change the text property of your text fields.

```
@IBOutlet var infoTextFields: [UITextField]!
@objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    infoProgressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    infoTextFields.forEach({
        $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    })
}
```

Comment: this did not work for me. it still kept the progress bar at 0 no matter how many I filled in

Comment: @BlueMoose check my edit. You could also use the same approach to check if the password (again) field matches the password field when the text changes and any validation you might need to do.

Comment: that worked thank you! Just wondering if my way would have worked with making a bool func to find if it is blank or not. Reason being everything you just added I don't understand as of yet

Comment: Float(infoTextFields) / Float(infoTextFields) it is wrong. You are passing an array to the Float initializer it wouldn't  even compile as it is. And `textFieldProgress(count: true)` you are always passing true to the method I don't know exactly what you mean by that. The user might delete the filed contents at any time.

Comment: well I will use what you gave me and try to learn more about it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are welcome. reduce iterate over all the fields ($1) and checks if the field is empty if it is true it just return the partial result ($0) otherwise it increases it adding 1. It returns the total number of fields that are not empty

Comment: regarding the control event it will call editingChanged method every time any of the fields changes the text property

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could use the UITextFieldDelegate method textFieldDidEndEditing for each of your text fields, and increase the width of your progress bar if the textField isn't empty.

Comment: I added the delegate. How do I attach the didendediting to outlet textfields?

Comment: after you add UITextFeildDelegate, you call the method 
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // your code here
    }

Comment: I believe the method operates on all text fields